# Exception "The specified named connection... with the EntityClient provider, or not valid." while loading WPF designer

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I'm writing an WPF application using Entity Framework and I have two controls, Window and UserControl which is embedded in Window. UserControl designer works fine, but Window designer returns an exception:

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not
intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

The exception points at line in UserControl code-behind where I create an instance of my entities.

```
public partial class Table : UserControl
{
    private MyEntities entity;
    public Table()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        entity = new MyEntities();
    }
}
```

When I run the app everything works fine.

**EDIT**
I found the solution here: [WPF designer won't load with entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455214/wpf-designer-wont-load-with-entity-framework) , although I'm using VS2010 and some time ago this approach (creating an instance of entities in the same place) worked fine, I don't know what broke it down.

Comment: sounds like it's trying to create an object context - either move that code to another place or make it conditional on whether you're in design mode

Answer (score 0):

The problem, most likely, is with the initialisation call in the design mode which is why code runs just fine.

Your Entity should be based on two files: FileName.edmx and FileName.Designer.vb (or .cs if using C#). When in design mode, the Window tries to create new instance of UserControl which in turn creates new instance (makes call to New) of the Entity. However, in design mode, VS doesn't look at the App.Config file (it looks there is debug mode) where the connection string for Entity is kept. Hence when VS tries to create the new Entity, one of the methods inside the Entity initialisation call fails because it receive Null connection string and as result you get your error.

A quick and dirty fix is to put in the connection string by hand in the FileName.Designer.vb (FileName.Designer.cs). If you open that file (you may have to click "Show All Files" in Solution Explorer), there should be, in Constructors region,

```
Public Sub New()
MyBase.New("name=Entity"," "Entity")
End Sub
```

or in C#

```
public New()
    {
        MyBase.New("name=Entity"," "Entity");
    }
```

if you replace the first argument of the call with the connection string from App.Config to get MyBase.New(ConnectionStringFromAppConfig," "Entity"), everything should work fine. One problem you might get is error message similar to "Keyword not supported: 'data source'." To fix this, you need to replace in the connection string you copied all the &quot with single quote. &quot is XAML way of coding single quote.

Hope that helps. If somebody were to contribute a more elegant solution - i would be grateful.